# How to start session and destroy session with sessionId in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, sessionid, express-session

I am using express-session module in node.js for session management. I created session for login and getting session Id But, when I checked with postman  it shows always same session Id for every login until until session destroy.

How can I create proper sessions with Id and how can I check whether session is live or not using session Id. Finally how to destroy the session with session using session Id.

what I tried is

```
   var userLogin = function(req,callback){
    var sess = req.session;
    var data = req.body;
    var query = "call userLogin(?,?)";
    var table = [data.email,data.pass];
    query = Repo.format(query,table);
    Repo.execute(query,function(err,result){
        if(err){

        }else{
            sess.email = data.email;
            sess.pass = data.pass;
            console.log("session ID is ",req.sessionID);
            if(req.sessionID){
                console.log("session is in");
            }
            else{
                console.log("session is out");
            }
            sess.destroy();
            console.log(req.sessionID);
             if(req.sessionID){
                console.log("aft session is in");
            }
            else{
                console.log("aft session is out");
            }

        }

        outPut(callback,err,result);
    });

}
```

Thank you.